# Apache - See HTTP 404 Error in error.log

Tags: apache2

I am trying to log and block unwanted connections to my domestic web page. I receive every day almost 200 connection trials using HTTP 1.0 from all over the world. I am using this rule to redirect the request to error 404:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

I would like to see this 404 errors in my error.log, as I already see the rest of 404 errors. By this way, with fail2ban I ban this IPs in the firewall. I am using this log level configuration:

```
LogLevel notice core:info
```

Is there a way to see modrewrite 404 errors in error.log?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568205/404-error-doesnt-appear-in-apache-error-log.